# Why am I getting an error while initializing oxidized?

Tags: yaml

I am an new to using Oxidized on Ubuntu 16.046 Server. I am trying to setup Oxidized for configuration management of my Cisco switch.

**config:**

```
username: muhsin
password: muhsin
model: cisco
interval: 3600
use_syslog: false
debug: false
threads: 30
timeout: 20
retries: 3
prompt: !ruby/regexp /^([\w.@-]+[#>]\s?)$/
rest: 0.0.0.0:8888
vars:
    enable: muhsin
groups: {}
pid: /home/oxidized/.config/oxidized/pid
input:
     default: ssh, telnet
     debug: false
     ssh:
     secure: false
output:
  default: file
  file:
    directory: /home/oxidized/configs
source:
   default: csv
   csv:
     file: /home/oxidized/.config/oxidized/router.db
     delimiter: !ruby/regexp /:/
   map:
      name: 0
      model: 1
      username: 2
      password: 3
    vars_map:
      enable: 4
    remove_secret: true
model_map:
cisco: ios
```

**router.db:**

```
192.168.223.10:cisco:muhsin:muhsin:muhsin
```

When I run oxidized, I get the following error:

> Error loading config: (): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 27 column 4.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is using inconsistent indenting, which makes it hard, especially as a novice using YAML, to detect what is going wrong.

- You indent the mapping that is value for the key `vars` with *four* positions.
- You indent the mapping that is the value for the key `input` with *five* positions.
- You indent the mapping that is the value for the key `output` with *two* positions.
- You indent the mapping that is the value for the key `map` with *three* positions.

Now that is all allowed, but making your file less readable for humans. But what is not allowed is that the mapping that is the value with the `source` partially with **three** positions (keys `default`, `csv` and `map`) and partially with **four** positions (`vars_map`, `remove_secret`).

Please note that rhere are however parsers for YAML that don't throw an error (although they should), and parse that as if `vars_map` and `remove_secret` were indented as much as `password`.

That you get line 27 as error indications is that the parser cannot correctly parse to the end, the mapping starting on that line (i.e the mapping starting with the key-value pair `default: csv`.

The `Oxidized` program could be more user friendly e.g. if you use my `ruamel.yaml` parser (for Python) you get an error message that  pinpoints that  error more accurately and in a much more useful way, so this is not YAML problem, but Oxidized not being user-friendly:

```
ruamel.yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
  in "<unicode string>", line 26, column 4:
       default: csv
       ^ (line: 26)
expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'
  in "<unicode string>", line 35, column 5:
        vars_map:
        ^ (line: 35)
```

(That the first line here is indicated as 26 is the typical starting to count a zero vs. starting to count at 1 difference).

Comment: So how would I best rewrite my code so as not to throw errors.

Comment: YAML is no code, it is a document describing data. If you just want to get rid of the error, you can remove lines at the end of the YAML document until it doesn't throw the error anymore. That of course changes the semantics of the loaded document for the program. The other thing you can do is outdent or indent the `vars_map` and `remove_secret` key. Which of those two is appropriate again depends on what Oxidized expects.

Comment: I finally got it running with editing the mapping


    map:
      name: 0
      ip: 1
      model: 2
      group: 3